# Changing query to expression in SSRS

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I am trying to turn a SQL query into an expression in SSRS; however, it seems like the behavior of the expression is not as I expected.  I have done this in the past, and I do not remember it behaving this way.  I am hoping someone cna shed some light on whether there is a better way to do this than I am currently trying.  I know I can use a Stored Procedure to work around this, but as this is a one time thing, I was hoping to avoid that.

```
="if '" & Join(Parameters!pParam.Value,"") & "' = 'X'
select * from table 1
else
select * from table 2"
```

I expected this to be treated as a single string, but it is not.  I need to do the following to treat it as a single string.

```
="if '" & Join(Parameters!pParam.Value,"") & "' = 'X' " & 
"select * from table 1 " & 
"else " & 
"select * from table 2"
```

Or I can put it all one line, which is easier with something short, but not really feasible with longer scripts.

Answer (score 0):

why not simply go like this in your dataset instead..

```
select * from table1 where @pParam.Value = 'X' 
union all 
select & from table2 where @pParam.Value <> 'X'
```

I am assuming that both tables return matching columns and data types.

Always select your columns explicitly rather than select *!

Comment: * is just for simplicity in example.  Not using it in code.  I don't think your solution works with multi-value parameters.  If I select * from table where pParam = 'X' and pParam is multi-value, I will get an error.

Comment: I verified just in case, but yes, this does cause an error with multi-valued parameters.  Your syntax is simpler after the JOIN has been applied, but I really need help with the SSRS expression, not so much whether IF...ELSE vs UNION ALL

Comment: Just to toss it out there, one reason I've done this before is on rare cases when I've needed dynamic SQL but I couldn't make a stored procedure.  You can paramterize table names in SSRS by converting the SQL to an expression and inserting the table based on an SSRS subscription without needing a stored proc.  But since it doesn't seem possible to wrap multi-line SQL scripts in one set of quotes, that's not a feasible thing to do anymore.